# Swift Error when trying to open other apps from my app | The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to let my app open the HBO Go app and automatically play a listed movie or tv show. For example, hbonow://asset?id=PROD773137 is returned as the variable link in the following example:

```
if let link = allSources[indexPath.row]["link"] as? String {
            let url  = NSURL(string: link)
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } 
        }
```

I've already added hbogo to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my info.plist, but I get the following error when I try to open HBO Go via my app:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hbonow://asset?id=PROD773137" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I can't seem to find any information on the error message. Does anyone have any experience with this error or recognize what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the HBO NOW app wasn't installed on the device I was using.

I expected the App Store to open up and direct users to the app they needed to download, but that's not how the canOpenURL works when it encounters this error.